# How to check for every item on the index 0 of an array if are falsy except for 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on a disable functionality for a button where I need to check that every item in the index zero of an array is falsy except for 2.

This is the composition of the array with each item:

```
my_team: startupMyTeamInfo.team.map(item => ({
          name: item.name,
          email: item.email,
          about: item.about,
          photo: item.photo,
          mobile: item.mobile,
          photo_id: item.photo_id,
          last_name: item.last_name,
          country_code_mobile: item.country_code_mobile,
        })),
});
```

The items I need to exclude are `photo` and `photo_id` because are not required.

This is the button:

```
                <PrimaryButton
                  type="button"               
                  onClick={handleUpdateApiCall}               
                  isDisabled={
                    (!startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].name …)
                  }
                />
```

So in that `isDisabled` prop I need something like

```
isDisabled={
 !startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].name &&
 !startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].email &&
 !startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].about &&
 !startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].mobile &&
 !startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].last_name &&
 !startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].country_code_mobile &&
}
```

like, is that the only way, going for every key or is there a more programatic way?

Comment: for specific fields, u haveto specify them, u can have a array of props name u want and through a loop check for them

Comment: _How to check for every item on the index 0_ well, there is only one item on index 0... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AnandUndavia index 0 contains every key after the dot. Like this is index 0 => `startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0]`, so index 0 contains `startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].name` and `startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0].email` and so on …

Comment: Oh okay, so you mean _Every key of the object that is at index 0_ ?

Comment: @AnandUndavia YES!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to extract the two permitted properties, and put the rest into an object with object rest syntax, and then check if `every` one of the rest object values are falsey:

```
const { photo, photo_id, ...rest } = startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0];
```

and then

```
isDisabled={ Object.values(rest).every(val => !val)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I present another approach to solve this problem.

First create another object containing only the selected fields from the `my_team` object using `reduce` method.

```
const team_subset = ['name', 'email', 'about', 'mobile', 'last_name', 'country_code_mobile'].reduce((o, k) => { o[k] = startupFourthStepForm.my_team[0][k]; return o; }, {});
```

After this, check if there's any `truthy` value in the new object and negate the result to store in `isDisabled` variable.

```
isDisabled = {!Object.keys((team_subset)).some(e => team_subset[e])};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_team: startupMyTeamInfo.team.map(item => {
  delete item.photo;
   delete item.photo_id;
   return item;
}
});
```

A slight better way of doing it